# Native telegram keyboard pop-ups after removing custom keyboard

Tags: bots, telegram

Let's imagine that a user starts a Telegram bot with "Start" button. The native keyboard (i.e. "abc" buttons at smartphone screen) is hidden at that moment (it will appear, i.e. maximize, if a user wants to type something by himself in the text field).

Then bot sends a reply with a new keyboard in "reply_markup", there's one button there, let's say "Share my location" with "request_location" set to true. Native keyboard remains hidden (minimized) at that case. Then user pushes a button at custom keyboard to share a location.

[Step 1: Keyboard is minimized.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KJ34.png)

Then bot removes used keyboard with "remove_keyboard" set to true, and native "abc" keyboard pop-ups (maximizes, showing that "abc" buttons) at that moment. Same behaviour in case of using "one_time_keyboad" option and not removing keyboard with "remove_keyboard".

[Step 2: Keyboard pop-ups.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLO3T.png)

Is there any option not to maximize "abc" keyboard after utilizing custom keyboad which has been used for "request_location" option, since I plan to work with inline_keyboard and callbacks after that, user is not expected to type anything by himself.

I expect that Telegram client for smartphone should maximize native "abc" keyboard only in case when user wants to type anything, i.e. when user selects text field at the bottom of a messenger client. And should hide that native keyboard when user hits main area with conversation above that field (iPhone) or hits "minimize keyboard button" (Android).